# GIT Centos 5 Problems

Tags: linux, git, centos, firewall, centos5

I've recently installed the GIT on a Rackspace cloud server. The installation was done through the Fedora EPEL packages.

In my IPTables I've added the accept for port 9418:
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9418 -j ACCEPT

Now on the server when I go to clone a repositary, I get this error.

```
git clone git://www_dev.####.com/public
Cloning into public...
fatal: Unable to look up www_dev.#####.com (port 9418) (Name or service not known)
```

Does anyone have an idea of what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DNS server can't resolve www_dev.####.com to an IP. If you can find the IP, add an entry to /etc/hosts and see if it works then. If so, you'll need to find a DNS server that knows that host name or else get it registered with a DNS server yourself.